# How to reconfigure Castle Windsor registration in unit test assembly

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Our project recently inherited some code that depends on Castle Windsor 2.5.2. For the purposes of my problem, the inherited code cannot be refactored.

In the new code's Model assembly, which houses the `IUnitOfWork` implementation, there is a default `IWindsorInstaller` implementation that has a default `Install` method that instantiates the EF component using `LifestyleType.PerWebRequest`.

Now, I'm a Castle Windsor noob, but it occurs to me that in any IoC architecture, the lowest-level assembly in the application should probably not register its own types; the highest-level assembly should register everything it needs.

That notwithstanding, the Model-level installer is a given at this point. So is 2.5.2; in 3.2 I believe I could just do this:

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromThisAssembly()
   .BasedOn<MyType>()
   .Configure(c => c.Lifestyle.Transient)
);
```

Any suggestions on how to do this in 2.5.2 would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "the highest-level assembly should register everything it needs." Yes, this concept is called the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).